# Can Wine not handle directory names ending in a dot?

Tags: linux, wine, bugs

Wine doesn't see files located under directories whose name ends in a dot.

I did the following:

```
cd ~/.wine/drive_c
mkdir dir.
touch dir./file
```

Then I used the windows file explorer to look at the directory which appeared empty.

```
wine explorer
```

This behavior seems to be the reason why the Canadian tax software "genutax" fails to load. It uses a directory named `users/{user}/Local Settings/Application Data/GenuSource Consulting Inc.`

Some more information:

```
$ /usr/bin/wine --version
wine-3.0 (Ubuntu 3.0-1ubuntu1)
```

I'm using an ext4 file system:

```
/dev/mapper/sth-sth_crypt on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered)
```

Comment: From the information you've provided, it seems you're using ancient versions of both Ubuntu (3.0 as opposed to the modern 20.04 LTS or 21.10) and Wine (3.0 as opposed to the modern stable 7.0 or development 7.2). At my end, it works fine with Wine 7.2 (albeit on Fedora rather than Ubuntu).

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS. I don't know why wine calls it "3.0-1ubuntu1" but I'm certainly not using Ubuntu 3.0. I updated wine to wine-7.0 which brought a lot of dependency problems but runs now but the bug persists. I still don't see the file inside the directory ending in a dot.

Comment: The "Ubuntu 3.0-1ubuntu1" is referring  to the wine package, saying that it is wine 3.0 compiled for Ubuntu.  It's not the Ubuntu version number.   And, yeah, wine 3.0 is ancient.   Ubuntu 18.04 is pretty old too.  If you can, upgrade both.  At least upgrade wine - if you're in luck, someone may have backported a more recent version of wine for 18.04 and made it available in a PPA.

Comment: I did update wine to 7.0 and the problem persists. I guess I am the only one who sees this behavior which makes me think there must be something wrong with my configuration.

Comment: I re-tested this on another system using Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS and wine-5.0 and see the same faulty behavior, i.e. wine can not handle directory names ending in a dot.